# Is it possible to set autosizing in interface builder for rotatable bg image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, rotation

I'm designing the UI with IB with a lot of images, and the default design orientation is landscape. However, I need to shrink the whole view to fit in portrait mode, by shrinking to the maximum allowed width and maintaining same aspect ratio for the view with it's inner images. The best way to imagine what I want to achieve is to imagine some landscape photo. When you rotate that to portrait it shrinks to the maximum width, centers vertically, but maintains the same aspect ratio. In my case, I want to shrink a view with its all inner subviews.

First, I'm manually resizing view frame to required size in viewWillApppear, and also calling setAutoresizesSubviews to resize all it's inner views. Those inner views - images are with "Aspect Fit" and all autosizing options set (to fill the available area on resized view). However, inner views pops out of the container: some images jumps to the top, text view expands to full portrait height. Is possible to set some kind of "view-container", then say - "view resize to size X and resize all your but only inside view-container area?

Comment: why don't you use two separate images for landscape and portrait mode..?

Comment: Because it's silly to maintain different images if no there's no aspect ration change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you design in IB you must check several things. First of all the "view container" properties, that is the view that contains all subview. In order to behave properly on rotation this view must be setup with right IB Autosizing properties, that is with the autosize lines (springs) and border lines (structs) correctly set. In your case you want your container to be exactly fit with the main view so enable the "structs" at the four sides and enable the "springs" inside. Play with this values and look at the "Example" displayed by IB.

Then you must instruct this container to properly behave with its subviews. So check in IB that "Autoresize subviews" and the content mode, if needed, (= "Mode") has the wished setting. 
At this point you check in the device or the simulator if your view is rotating and rising properly.

Then you must take care of the content of this view, which is a UIImageView. This must be centered, so remove the structs, and autoresized, so set the springs. Then set the content mode  to Aspect Fit or Aspect Fill at your wish.

These settings should work. For more complex stuff, you must programmatically set things.